# Can machine code be separated into several parts with fixed distance?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Opcode can have `JMP` command jumping to an address that also mean another instruction:

```
JE $+42 ; 74 40, from 0001 it's an INC EAX
```

but usually it makes a jump far.

The problem is that I also write one program separated sometimes, e.g. when the skipped space is intended to do some other stuff, or maybe it's a fun call. Thus separated code seems nothing wrong.

So is it allowed?